# ATmega328p, interrupt from timer0

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, atmega

I have problem with interrupt from timer0 in µC ATmega328p.
Program doesn't show on LCD anything when interrupt invoke function `showOnScreen()`. When function `showOnScreen()` is invoked in main loop, everything works. Any ideas why it doesn't work when I use interrupt?

```
int main(void){
    DDRD = 0xf0;
    PORTD = 0x0f;

    LCD_Initalize();
    LCD_Clear();
    LCD_Home();

    i2cSetBitrate(100);

    DS3231_init();
    DS3231_setTime(0 ,0 ,0);
    DS3231_setDate(0, 1, 1, 1);

    showOnScreenInit();
    sei();
    while(1) {
        button();
    }
    return 0;
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){
showOnScreen();
}

void showOnScreenInit(void){
    TCCR0A |= (1<<WGM01); //CTC
    TCCR0A |= (1<<CS02)|(1<<CS00);// prescaler 1024
    OCR0A = 100; 
    TIMSK0 |= (1<<OCIE0A); //compare match
}
```

EDIT: I check `TCNT0` register and, this register is equal to 0 all the time, so clock doesn't started.

```
void showOnScreen(void){
    if (menuFlag == 0){
        DS3231_getDateTime(&dateTime);
        LCD_Clear();
        show_time(&dateTime);
    }
}
```

Rest functions are in DS3231 library:

```
void DS3231_getDateTime( TDATETIME * dt ) {
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t buf[7];
    TWI_read_buf( DS3231_ADDR, 0x00, 7, buf );
    for( i=0; i<7; i++ ) dt->bytes[i] = bcd2dec( buf[i] );
}

void show_time( TDATETIME * dt ) {
    char time[8];
    sprintf(time, "%02d:%02d:%02d", dt->hh, dt->mm, dt->ss);
    LCD_WriteText(time);
}
```

Comment: It might be a goodd idea to show the function in question. However, it is likely a bad idea to call that function from an ISR. Note that you invoke undefined behaviour by calling a function with a definition different from its (implicit) declaration. Use a C99 or C11 compiler and you shall get warnings.

Comment: If I only had a cent (whichever currency) every time I heard " function/module/program/... XY is ok". Use a debugger. Still, it is a very bad Idea to call a function which takes significant time unnecessarily in an interrupt handler. It will become definitively a problem if you also output something in your normal code. Just my 2ct, but I only do this job for some decades, you possibly have more experience.

Comment: I guess you have to set a clock source and start the timer via `TCCR0B` register. (Sorry if any of your functions already does this)

Comment: @santisg I have already checked the function, and it seems you only initialized `TCCR0A`, `OCR0A` and `TIMSK0` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a typo and the clock isn't provided to the timer, so the timer remains stopped.

Try

```
TCCR0B |= (1<<CS02)|(1<<CS00);// prescaler 1024
```

instead of

```
TCCR0A |= (1<<CS02)|(1<<CS00);// prescaler 1024
```